# Status bar blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I'm working on UI design in iOS. When I try to add a subview into my root view, a blank appears under the status bar.

```
_tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
_tableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:_tableViewController.view];
```

[image: blank]

`TableViewController` is the class I define in other file.

But if I use `UITableView` instead, everything will be ok.

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

[image: no blank]

What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line,

```
_tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
```

That should be UITableViewController right?

Also in simplistic terms a UITableViewController is a UITableView already in a UIViewController, so there shouldn't be a need to add it as a subview. This is why it respects the status bar and is full screen.

The UITableView is just like any other view and doesn't respect such things. I hope this helps! It may be easier to use Storyboards if you are mainly doing UI work?